What do I do after installing a logger like NLog or Log4Net?
I don't have a lot of experience with loggers, so I know this is going to sound like a dumb question. But I can't find the answer to it anywhere. Okay, I install NLog or Log4Net, configure the one I installed, and then what?
Is the rest automatic?
Do I need to go through my code and try/catches and add the correct logger code?
Sorry for the silly question.
UPDATE: I want to thank all those that responded. It sounds like the best option is to just try it an see how it goes from there. I didn't see any definate answers, but the fact that most of these logging solutions are based on ILogger, it would make sense that it would capture most errors automatically, so to speak. On the other hand, it also seems like for specific cases, you would add a call in a try/catch block.

You need to go through your code and log what you want logged.

I'd recommend to play around with it. Try the respective API, try with MS logging abstraction, try structured logging ...

It depends a little. Many frameworks in .NET core log some things to the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging abstractions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging). If your code, or the frameworks you use, are logging that way, then you may only need to configure those abstractions to point to your chosen logging framework, and some of those log messages will come through (depending on how you have it configured). Otherwise, you'll need to write code that invokes a logger to tell it what information you want logged.

Coding helmet. Thats a funny one. Not helpful at all, but funny. Ever been snipe hunting?

Remember to use UseNLog() / AddNLog() to register NLog as logging-provider for ILogger<T>. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6

I want to thank all those that responded. It sounds like the best option is to just try it an see how it goes from there. I didn't see any definate answers, but the fact that most of these logging solutions are based on ILogger, it would make sense that it would capture most errors automatically, so to speak. On the other hand, it also seems like for specific cases, you would add a call in a try/catch block.
